# Should i destroy dynamically added CodeMirror editor?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, codemirror

[CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#overview)

I need to:

- create a single instance of codemirror editor dynamically
- change it's current value sometimes (by destroying it ant initilizing again?)
- change type of editor - sometimes I need the editor itself, sometimes I need [diff mode](http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html)

This is happening in SinglePageApplication.
How should i handle it? should i create textarea and then convert it in and out codemirror each time as described [here](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_static) (method `cm.toTextArea()`). Or there is another more clearer way?

Answer (score 2):

You can update the value of an existing editor with its `setValue` method, and change its mode with `editor.setOption("mode", ....)`.

To get rid of an editor, just detach it from the DOM and make sure you don't keep any references to it, and the garbage collector will take care of it.